# Are dark troops practical to train at town hall 7?

Tags: clash-of-clans

At Town Hall 7, you get a Dark Barracks and Dark Elixir storage. However, you do not get a Dark Elixir drill. Without this collector, is it practical to train these troops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is...  kinda.  DE troops aren't going to be the backbone of your army at TH7, but they can still be useful anyhow.

You can earn dark elixir, either through clan wars or via raiding other bases.  So if you train DE troops and use that to raid/win DE, technically that's a win.

Minions are by far the cheapest flying unit in the game, in terms of both resources and camp space.  Combining them with the barbs and archers in the ["BARCH" farming strategy](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/tips-tricks-rapid-raiding-around-town-hall-7-clash-clans/) makes the also popular BAM troop combo.  The minions allow you to pierce deeper into bases your barbs & archers couldn't normally get into.  This can help you hit DE drills and storages you wouldn't normally be able to otherwise.

Also it's worth noting that you can use [overtraining](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/top-10-best-kept-secrets-in-clash-of-clans/) to store your DE in your Dark Barracks when you're not playing.  (the tip is about regular elixir, but DE works the same way)  Just queue up DE troops when your camps are full and the elixir will be spent, but you can cancel them and get the DE back later.

This can help you save up or protect quantities of DE that you would otherwise lose to raiding.  Whether or not you consider this "training DE troops" is kind of questionable, since you'll generally cancel the troops rather than train them.

In my personal experience at TH7, I used minions occasionally (usually I had around 10-15 trained at any given time) to hit DE storages during raids.  I managed to earn my Barbarian King this way before ever having a drill.

Comment: The "over training" tip was great. I have never heard this before, but is brilliant to reduce loss in attacks!

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes, You can be rushed town hall 7 however you can get dark troops if you have a dark elixir collector and you if you get a dark elixir drill if you really wan. And you can get dark troops if you get the dark barracks and if you do it correctly you will get the dark troops for sure.

Comment: What? Clarify your answer please.